# multidatespicker jquery jquery-ui-dist

Tags: jquery, laravel-5

estoy implenetando un pequeño sistema con laravel y para dar solucion a la seleccion multiple de fechas me decidi por utilizar jquery multidatespicker (http://dubrox.github.io/Multiple-Dates-Picker-for-jQuery-UI/), mi problema es que al correr el comando npm run dev me envia el siguiente error

> his dependency was not found:
>
> - jquery-ui-dist in ./node_modules/jquery-ui-multidatespicker/jquery-ui.multidatespicker.js

esta dependencia es llamada dentro del archivo query-ui.multidatespicker.js con la siguiente funcion

```
 (function(factory) {
  if (typeof define === "function" && define.amd) {
    define(["jquery", "jquery-ui-dist"], factory);
  } else {
    factory(jQuery);
  }
```

He estado navegando por unas horas y no he encontrado documentacion a dicho problema.